# Wifi login detection for Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, wireless-networking

OSX detects when login is required after you join public wifi and pops up a small window that's supposed to open the provider's login page (although this doesn't always work properly in my experience).

Is there any third party tool that can do this for Windows XP/7?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing magic about this. The OS just hits a specific URL and if it gets redirected to a log in page, it will open the browser.

There's little point writing a tool to do this. You can open a browser and do it yourself just as easily.

Comment: -1 I know what is going on behind the scenes at a technical level. OSX, and iOS have it, and it's very convenient (when it works). I'm looking for something that does it on Windows. I want my computer to make my life easier :)